# Data entry force in excel cell only if I want to change a separate cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to make an excel file that forces the user entering data in the file to not leave cells blank.  But I only want to force the user to enter the data if they change a certain cell.

This is for a scoring sheet that must have supporting information entered to input the score.

For example, I select cell `D12`, which may already have data in it:

- If I don't try to change the cell, then nothing happens and I can select any other cell in the file.
- If I attempt to change the cell `D12`, then I must have data entered in cell `E12`.  If I don't enter data in `E12`, then I can't change `D12`.

Answer (score 1):

You could, for that specific task, do something along the lines of:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Address = "$E$12" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        Select Case Range("E12").Value
            Case ""
                Range("D12").Locked = True
            Case Else
                Range("D12").Locked = False
        End Select
        ActiveSheet.Protect
    End If
End Sub
```

In the code for the sheet.
If you use a protected sheet, this will lock/unlock D12 based upon manipulation of E12.

If you don't like how that works, or don't want to protect the sheet, you could try something similar, but completely different.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$D$12" Then
        If Range("E12").Value = "" And Range("D12").Value <> "" Then
            Range("D12") = ""
            MsgBox "Please enter E12 before D12"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

With this, if you enter something in D12 while E12 is empty, it will be deleted and a Messagebox will appear and tell you why.
`If Target.Address = "$D$12" Then` Is optional, and can be removed completely if you always want to check, in case they edit D12 and then delete the value in E12. Or you could change it to 
`If Target.Address = "$D$12" Or Target.Address = "$E$12" Then`
For that case.